# Error running postgresql96-setup initdb with Ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to automate the installation of a PostgreSQL database using Ansible.

However, the following task:

```
- name: Initialize Postgres
  command: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
  become: true
```

Results in this error:

```
fatal: [nexus-staging.chop.edu]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb",
    "delta": "0:00:00.043311",
    "end": "2017-02-16 23:39:12.512727",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": true
        },
        "module_name": "command"
    },
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2017-02-16 23:39:12.469416",
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log"
    ],
    "warnings": []
}
```

The error in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log` is:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup: line 140: runuser: command not found
```

What is interesting is that if I run `sudo /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb` on the host, it runs successfully...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `PATH` environment variable defined explicitly in the task:

```
- name: Initialize Postgres
  command: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  become: true
```

Most likely the value of the path is set differently for interactive and non-interactive shell sessions.

---

Or locate the `runuser` executable and add the path before running the script:

```
command: PATH=/runuser/location:${PATH} /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```